# Object collection optimisation

Tags: optimization, linq-to-objects

I'm struggling with something I'm sure I should be able to do quite quick with Linq-to-Obj

Have 27 flowers, need a collection of `Flower[]` containing 5 items split over, roughly 6 records;

`List<Flowers[]>` should contain 6 `Flowers[]` entities, and each `Flowers[]` array item should contain 5 flower objects.

I currently have something like:

```
List<Flowers[]> flowers;
int counter = 0;
List<Flowers>.ForEach(delegate (Flower item) {
    if (counter <= 5){
        // add flowers to array, add array to list
    }
});
```

I'm trying to optimise this as it's bulky.

**[Update]**

I can probably to an array push on objects, removing the items I'v already run through, but is there not an easier way?

Comment: So you are effectively looking to do the reverse of `SelectMany()` and break out a single collection of 27 objects into 6 groups of 5.  Do you care which 5 are grouped together?  Do they have to be in sequential groupings, or grouped by other criteria?  Or can it be random?

Comment: I'm not too worried about the grouping, and random is totally acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ITEMS_IN_GROUP = 5;
var result = list.Select((Item, Index) => new { Item, Index })
                 .GroupBy(x => x.Index / ITEMS_IN_GROUP)
                 .Select(g => g.Select(x=>x.Item).ToArray())
                 .ToList();
```

You may also want to try [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)'s `Batch`